# How should a ListView adapter be structured when random access to a data source is not available?

Tags: android

Examples of smooth scrolling implementations of ListView data adapters often require random access to the data source. The widely cited view holder pattern provides an implementation for getView, that obtains data based on a position/index passed to it.

My question is, what pattern can be employed in cases where random access to the data source is not efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to cache the data in a List of objects that can be accessed in random order, or consider using something other than a List View (ScrollView?) to display your objects.

Answer (score 0):

The position is not related to the ViewHolder pattern at all.  All the ViewHolder pattern does really is cache the `findViewById` calls which can be expensive in Android.  Setting the fields of the ViewHolder with the data source (based on the position) is independent of what the ViewHolder actually does.

Comment: Correct, the pattern is independent of the data source design. However the crux of my question is how can I still use this pattern combined with a data source that does not permit random access.

Comment: I have updated the question wording to better reflect my query. The emphasis on the view holder pattern itself has been removed.